# Input array loop on controller laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have inputs array and i need to make a foreach but laravel $request->all() only return last one:

url:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/ofertas?filter_pais=1&filter_pais=2&filter_pais=3
```

controller:

```
public function filtroOfertas(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
}
```

result:

```
{"filter_pais":"3"}
```

result should return 1, 2 and 3 and i need to make a foreach in filter_pais.
Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [] at the key of query string.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/ofertas?filter_pais[]=1&filter_pais[]=2&filter_pais[]=3
```

It will be parsed as array.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated parameters make no sense and should be avoided without exception.

But looking at other solutions, there are several:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/api/ofertas/{r}', 'Controller@index');
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function index($r)
    {
        $query  = explode('&', $r);
        $params = array();

        foreach($query as $param)
        {
            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param);
            $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
        }

        // $params contains all parameters

}
```

**Given that the URL has no question marks:**

```
http://localhost:8000/api/ofertas/filter_pais=1&filter_pais=2&filter_pais=3
```